# How can I get /dev/dvd to exist after a reboot

Tags: 14.04, dvd

In Ubuntu 14.04, /dev/dvd does not exist. If I symlink it like this:
sudo ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/dvd

Things that are looking for /dev/dvd (like apparently the default Movies app) will see it and run with it.

The problem is, the very next reboot and the symlink is gone.

How can I configure things so that /dev/dvd exists even after a reboot?

Comment: I've seen a couple of apps that haven't switched off of /dev/dvd but they can simply be changed in their preferences. Videos (totem) doesn't seem to be one that uses /dev/dvd (nor can it be changed). So better to fix your apps. If really bent on keeping /dev/dvd I can show you one way that'll work until udev is updated (which may never happen..

Comment: Oddly enough, now, when I insert a DVD, Ubuntu is asking what I want to do and if I select the option to use Videos (Totem) they are working. I honestly don't know what changed and why it wasn't doing this yesterday.

Comment: Sounds like you're okay then. For info purposes the smylink was disappearing on boot because you have no (udev) rule creating the /dev/dvd link.